# React Native email validation without regex

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-native, validation

I want to validate an email address in react-native TextInput, but without using regex. I want to validate it by the native way, like in html, where we can do it by defining input type="email".

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at libraries like [validate.js](https://github.com/ansman/validate.js).

A completely native way like `<input type="email>"` is not available within React Native.
Regex is indeed problematic for email addresses as there are incredibly many cases and any regular expressions will very likely cause false positives or vice versa.
The official [RFC822](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) regex is extremely obscure and slow.
Good validation libraries use BNF Parsers to make this process more efficient.

As a security engineer I need to point out though, that front-end validation is never enough, no matter how good it is.

Requests can easily be forged which makes backend validation mandatory for all cases. Just send an email to the provided address and require the user to click a unique link in it that you map to a `validationCompleted` call in your app.